# Interaction pairs- how they can cause movement

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces

Back to basics with this question but I really want to make sure I understand this concept.

Newton's third law states that 'every action has an opposite and equal reaction', which we can see through interaction pairs. However, I'm a little confused on what is happening. I read the answer to 'With Newton's third law, why are things capable of moving?' by Andrew C, however in his diagram, he had a force called *F matchbox*, and I was just wondering shouldn't the matchbox counteract this force through the interaction pair that it forms?

I find it helpful to visualise concepts, and so basically I have come up with this little thought experiment but I wasn't exactly sure if it's the right way to look at things. Essentially, I imagine a man jumping, and visualise the force the man is exerting on the Earth. I then imagine how silly it would be that the Earth itself moved because of this force, however I then see that the man has risen in the air due to the reaction force. In this way I was able to explain why interaction pairs, even though they are balanced could lead to movement and acceleration.

**BTW** I realise that a similar question may have been asked before, but the answers I have seen just don't fully explain what's going on and I don't have enough reputation to comment. :(

Answer (score 0):

The third law says "if body A exerts a force on body B, body B exerts and equal and opposite (direction) force on body A.  **In terms of causing motion, these forces do not cancel.**  If we are evaluating the motion of body A, we include all the forces acting on body A, and this includes the force body B exerts on A, but not the force that body A exerts on B.   The force that body A exerts on body B does not figure in determining the motion of body A.  It only figures in determining the motion of body B.